# Bootstrap button ; javascript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this piece of code in my form:

```
<a onclick="discount()"><button class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color:#92CD00; color:black">Discount</button></a>
```

The discount function reduces the price by the given value.

When I click on the button, `discount()` executes, but it immediately flickers back to the original value! Why? Please tell me if I am executing the button properly.

Comment: Er... post your code please.

Comment: Agreeing with @Ennui.  Please post the code for your `discount()` function.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have a button inside an anchor.

Comment: @Quentin Do you have a source that you can cite on that?  As far as I can tell, it's acceptable.  [anchor tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) can contain any [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content) for which the [button element qualifies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button).

Comment: Content model: "Transparent, but there must be **no interactive content descendant**." — http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element

Comment: @Quentin very cool!  Ever since HTML5 allowed for block level elements inside of anchor tags, I had been wondering where the line was drawn. Thank you very much for the clarification.

Comment: His button is not interactive, so it's acceptable code. Test with normal code, it'll work, though I'll never use such coding

Answer (score 0):

You can separate your functionalities (content, behavior, styling) and bind your button behavior with jQuery instead.

CSS (styling):

```
#btn_discount {
    background-color: #92CD00;
    color: black;
}
```

HTML (content):

```
<button id="btn_discount" class="btn btn-primary">Discount</button>
```

JS (behavior):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#btn_discount").click(
        var current_price = my_app.get_price();
        var discount_value = my_app.get_discount();
        var new_price = my_app.discount(current_price, discount_value);
        my_app.set_price(new_price);
    );
});

var my_app = {
    price: 0,
    discount: 0,
    get_price: function() {
        return this.price;
    },
    set_price: function(new_price) {
        this.price = new_price;
    },
    get_discount: function() {
        return this.discount_value;
    },
    set_discount: function(new_discount_value) {
        this.discount = new_discount_value;
    },
    discount: function(price, value) {
        var reduced_price;
        ....
        return reduced_price;
    }
};
```